# Adding headers to a CSV

Tags: text-processing, csv, sql

I have an SQL command which fetches you an output like

```
70
138
200
```

This is stored in a csv and I have added headers to it but appears like

```
A,B,C
70
138
200
```

I wanted it to look like

```
A 70
B 138
C 200
```

or

```
A
70
B
138
C
200
```

or

```
A,B,C
70,138,200
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of the input file?

Comment: `A,B,C
70,138,200` is the correct format you should look for. You need to change your query to get it to return `70,138,200`, then add your header.

Comment: is it possible that your SQL query has an option to include the column names as well?

Comment: Adding the headers and doing the formatting in the SQL query seem to be the most straightforward solution here...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your original data (with no headers and with the data in a single column) is in the file called `file`:

```
$ { printf 'A\nB\nC\n'; cat file; } | paste -d, - - -
A,B,C
70,138,200
```

The compound command `{ ...; }` creates the output

```
A
B
C
70
138
200
```

The `paste` utility reads this and organises it into three columns (the three dashes) with commas as delimiters.

Alternative formulation:

```
printf 'A\nB\nC\n' | cat - file | paste -d, - - -
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use paste

```
paste -d " " inputLetters inputNumbers
```

to have

```
A 70
B 138
C 200
```

The sources are

```
$ cat inputLetters
A
B
C

$ cat inputNumbers
70
138
200
```